# memory usage in oops

Tags: oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [will changing all code to object oriented make memory usage bigger or smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894465/will-changing-all-code-to-object-oriented-make-memory-usage-bigger-or-smaller)

Hi all,
Is it true that object oriented programs takes more memory than procedural?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894465/will-changing-all-code-to-object-oriented-make-memory-usage-bigger-or-smaller

Comment: Exact duplicate, voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. I would advise not listening to the person who told you that.

Answer (score 1):

No, the amount of memory you allocate is the amount of memory used.

There are languages that use Garbage collectors and JIT compilers that use extra memory (C#, Java), but that's just language specific and has nothing much to do with the fact that they are OOP.